# SSRS Populate Dropdown from Dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

SSRS Populate Dropdown from Dataset.

My Dataset has list of customers made shopping in multiple grocery stores which are located in multiple cities for the period of last 90 days.

Requirement is, On selecting GroceryStoreA which is in the Dropdownlist box, i can see a second dropdownlist with multiple cities.

I can view the report for GroceryStoreA only for a SelectedCity. But my dataset has duplicate values of GroceryStoreA and duplicatevalues for Cities.

How should i populate the dropdownlist from Dataset with distinct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query powering the dataset that's behind your parameters needs to return unique values only instead of every single row. You can use either `SELECT DISTINCT` or alternatively the `GROUP BY` clause to achieve that, depending on what else you want to use the dataset for.

Comment: Under Parameters - Available Values  - Choose available values for Parameter. Get values from query.  Doesnt give option for Distinct

Comment: I mean in the dataset - Right Click the Dataset and go to Query, then include the `SELECT DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` in the Query that's fetching data for that dataset.